# Can't get Python scripts to execute on Mac WebServer

Tags: python, macos, webserver

I am having trouble getting python scripts to run on my Mac WebServer (Mac OS 10.13.5). All it will do is display the code. It won't execute it. Things i've tried:

• chmod +x for my script

• header in script is #!/usr/bin/python

• uncommented LoadModule cgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_cgi.so

• Set Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables" to:

```
AllowOverride None
options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .tcl .py
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

• sudo apachectl stop

• sudo apachectl start

• also tried sudo apachectl restart

Here is the script I'm trying to run:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import pyromat as pm
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np

    # Create a temperature array in steps of 10K
    T = np.arange(300,2000,10)
    # Get the Oxygen object
    O2 = pm.get('ig.O2')

    f = plt.figure(1)   # Call up figure 1
    f.clf()         # clear it (if it already exists)
    ax = f.add_subplot(111) # Create an axes object on the figure
    ax.plot(T, O2.cp(T))    # Add a curve to that axes
    ax.set_xlabel('Temperature (K)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Specific Heat (kJ/kg/K)')
    f.savefig('cp.png') # Make a file
```

No luck at all. Still just displaying the code. Python is installed and working. Script works fine when run in terminal. Any ideas?

I've since put a hello world script and it displayed fine. I'm guessing it's that i'm calling the 3 modules and maybe it's not finding them? Getting Internal Server Error now.

Comment: What is the script trying to do? Are you using a framework (such as Flask) to allow your python variables to be displayed as HTML? Right now it seems you are just opening your python file and displaying it through your browser instead of as a webpage.

Comment: it is supposed to create a png file of a graph from data.

Comment: where do i find the error log? tried changing the shebang line and got an internal server error. still getting it after reverting.

Comment: It isn't clear what your goal is exactly. If you want to execute some python from within a server you need to use a python framework to call the script and display the results on a web page.

Comment: I have python installed on my Mac and thought by enabling it on WebServer it would run. I was able to get a simple Hello World script to run now but my other script will not. Perhaps it's due to calling a module?

Comment: Simply copy-pasting your code makes it annoying and difficult to read. Please edit your original post and use formatting.

Comment: i think my problem is that it is not importing the python modules i need to make the  script run properly. would i need to install them somewhere else where WebServer can access them? works fine in Terminal.